# Multiple filter with same value Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an JSON object like this

```
$scope.list = [{
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "NAME1",
    "Category": "Category1",
    "Code": "Code1"
}, {
    "ID": 2,
    "Name": "NAME2",
    "Category": "Category1",
    "Code": "Code2"
}, {
    "ID": 3,
    "Name": "NAME3",
    "Category": "Category1",
    "Code": "Code3"
}, {
    "ID": 4,
    "Name": "NAME4",
    "Category": "Category3",
    "Code": "Code4"
}, {
    "ID": 5,
    "Name": "NAME5",
    "Category": "Category3",
    "Code": "Code5"
}]
```

And I have just one input. I want to filter the ng repetive directive with only the objects that have values similar to "Name" or "Category" properties. How can I do that? For example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText">
<div ng-repeat="obj in list | filter:{Name:searchText.name}"
| filter:{Category:searchText.category}">

</div>
```

I dont want to search by Code propertie.
Thanks

Comment: You want something like this: `ng-repeat="obj in list | filter:{obj.Name:searchText, obj.Category: searchText}"`?

Comment: Yes, exactly, something like that!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a model variable and use it for filter,

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    
 $scope.list = [{
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "NAME1",
    "Category": "Category1",
    "Code": "Code1"
}, {
    "ID": 2,
    "Name": "NAME2",
    "Category": "Category1",
    "Code": "Code2"
}, {
    "ID": 3,
    "Name": "NAME3",
    "Category": "Category1",
    "Code": "Code3"
}, {
    "ID": 4,
    "Name": "NAME4",
    "Category": "Category3",
    "Code": "Code4"
}, {
    "ID": 5,
    "Name": "NAME5",
    "Category": "Category3",
    "Code": "Code5"
}];
  $scope.search = function (row) {
    return (angular.lowercase(row.Name).indexOf($scope.searchText || '') !== -1 || angular.lowercase(row.Category).indexOf($scope.searchText || '') !== -1);
};
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    Search: <input ng-model="searchText">
  <table id="searchTextResults">
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Category</th></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="item in list | filter:search">
  <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
  <td>{{item.Category}}</td>
</tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thats the normal way, but I dont want to filter by Code. I need more efficiency because I load like 3500 items and if i search by all properties the ng repeat takes to many time doing the filter. Thanks

Comment: so what do you want to do

Comment: search only by Name and Category, no by ID and Code

Comment: Thats works too, but is not what i am looking. Now yo are showing just Name and Category, but if in your input you write the name of the category the filter is going to work too, searching the category propertie

Comment: @JoseR.Chacón you wanted it to filter by category and name